# Storing values in variable like multidimensional array value using FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have multidimentional array functions which are obtaining the values from database sqlite .

```
var myarray = [];
```

The array values will be like the below :

```
myarray[0][0] = "ABC";
myarray[0][1] = "abc";
...
...
...
myarray[3][1] = "GHI";
```

I need to store array values like this in a variable :

```
var  md2 = [[myArray[0][0], myArray[0][1]],
    [myArray[1][0], myArray[1][1]],
    [myArray[2][0], myArray[2][1]],
    [myArray[3][0], myArray[3][1]]];
```

How do i declare the above array values dynamically?

I tried the below :

```
for(var t =0; t<md2.length; t++){

var g = 0;

md2 = [myarray[t][g],myarray[t][g+1]];

}
```

This above is not working .

My expected Result is this using for loop:

```
var  md2 = [[myArray[0][0], myArray[0][1]],
        [myArray[1][0], myArray[1][1]],
        [myArray[2][0], myArray[2][1]],
        [myArray[3][0], myArray[3][1]]];
```

How can i do that using for loop or other.
Suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just make  copy of first array?

Comment: just decalare a new array and use push method

Comment: @charlietfl . I m just need to store `[myArray[0][0]` ...... values dynamically using loop conditions. because the myArray length may differ from databale

Comment: @kpsingh can u tell me how to do that dynamically

Comment: Your expected output is bit difficult to understand. Can you simply it further?

Comment: From your explanation and code example, it looks like what you want is this: `var md2 = myArray;`. That's because the content of `md2` is exactly the same as `myArray`. That's why people are asking what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @User Android can you show us in which format you are getting this data from server (JSON output)?

Comment: `var  md2 = [].concat(myarray )` would give you exactly the same as what you have now. Or `var md2 = myarray.slice()`

Comment: @charlietfl very Thanks , Ur two answers perfectly worked . pls put ur comment as answer for credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these approaches will give you a copy of myarray which is all you are doing in your code as it is now

```
var md2 = [].concat(myarray);
// OR
var md2 = myarray.slice();
```

Both are non destructive and will leave `myarray` untouched

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/3r6p1o3x/)

```
var md2 = [];
for (var t=0; t < myarray.length; t = t+2){
   if (myarray[t] && myarray[t+1]) {
         md2.push( [ myarray[t], myarray[t+1] ] );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks frd , this not working for me but tq for spending time :) ..... But working in JQfiddle

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional array is created simply by building on a "normal" array.

```
 var aa = new Array(3)
 for(var i=0; i<3;i++) {
    aa[i]=new Array(3);
    for(var j=0; j<3;j++) {
       aa[i][j] = j;
    }
  }
  console.log(aa);

 Output: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for store value from multidimensional to single

```
var md2 = [];
var cnt = 0;
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
md2[i] = myArray[i];
}
```